# no matter what i do my tablet has 0mb space available

Tags: internal-storage, storage, troubleshooting

Even after a factory reset when I go to settings>storage my tablet has about 120 MBS of space taken up between apps, audio, cached, and misc. But 0 available, can't download anything because of it, and I don't know if there's some sort of virus  that does this or what but any ideas on how to fix would be appreciated.I have an envizen V917G 9" 8GB Android 4.2.2

Comment: Please don't ask the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score -2):

Try getting a memory card if you don't have one. Move apps from Phone to SD card. Hope this helps.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the question,its a tablet and the problem is I have no apps on my tablet and can't get any